# RedShift or DynamoDb

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, data-science

I have a project with python with panda dataframe, i need a database to scan large row counts for every client 
Now in MySql the query's of database take a long time to be execute i need a better performance with new database system, but i don't now what is the best option for select: RedShift or DynamoDb, because i need speed to execute large query's insert/delete/select from two tables, i explain the now system operation description bellow:

Tables: sales, sales_simulate, this tables do not need a relational with other tables only column client_id that get the id's from datafile source when begin the process, this file import every month to simulate data

**Premised: the system is for only 1 admin which run in vps, only 1 large query for client and sales simulate and change values every month and a i need re-calculate the data from 3 year ago, this system only run 1 time every month**

**THE PROBLEM:**
To get a 30k clients_id query's = ~8s 
To get a sales of each client take = ~4s 
Process with python (calculate sales and more) take  = 2m 
To Delete/Insert query every 1k proceded clients 1kk row's take = ~12m 
1k clients = ~14m 
~14m * 30k clients  = 420m / 60 = 7 hrs <- total

**Example data:**
I have 30k clients 
I need get a sales for each client from 3 years before to now current date 
1 client have 4~10k rows of sales registers and i have 30k clients: 30k * 4k  = 120k max 300k * 
example:

```
client_id | date                | amount
   1        2019-02-01 12:33:44     100.0
   1        2019-02-01 12:34:44     100.0
   1        2019-02-01 20:54:44     100.0
   2        2019-02-01 08:54:44     62.0
   2        2019-02-01 23:54:44     60.0
```

I get the total amount of date result this:

```
client_id | date                | amount
       1        2019-02-01         300.0
       2        2019-02-01         122.0
```

Now with pandas full the dataframe for each client from 3 year before date to now date:

```
client_id | date                | amount
   1        2070-02-20         0
   ....
   1        2019-02-01         300.0
  ...
   1        2020-02-20         0
```

Then when have fill dataframe with all dates with all client's, i sent to save in database 1.125k row's for each client: 1.125k * 30k (clients) = 33,750,000 of rows

**Now i try with save in data-part, every 1000k proceded clients, i save the rows on table, 1.125k * 1k = 1,125,000 of rows**

Comment: Software recommendation requests are explicitly off topic here -- back when we allowed them, commercial software vendors asked fake questions through sockpuppet accounts to shill their products in answers (and also, software comparison questions get out-of-date quickly as projects change, get retired, etc -- making them not great for something that strives to be a FAQ). See #4 in the "some questions are still off topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I don't think you're trying to sell something. I'm just explaining why the rules are what they are.

Comment: For an alternate Stack Exchange site where this question *would* be allowed, see [softwarerecs.se] -- but on that site like all others, do read the rules before posting.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

**Amazon Redshift** is a data warehouse. It excels in performing complex SQL queries across wide tables and billions of rows. Best used for querying, not as a transaction store. (That is, the data should be loaded in bulk rather than updated a few rows at a time.)

**Amazon DynamoDB**, being a non-relational database, is excellent and highly performant for updating and retrieving data based on a specific key. However, it should not be used to "scan" all data that is stored. (Use secondary index to locate data based on non-primary keys.)

So, if you don't need relational (SQL) queries and you're mostly working on one row at a time, DynamoDB is ideal. If you're having to search for data across many rows (eg using `WHERE`), then a relational database is more advisable.